# Which data structures to use when storing multiple entities with multiple query criteria?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

There is a storage unit, with has a capacity for N items. Initially this unit is empty.
The space is arranged in a linear manner, i.e. one beside the other in a line. 
Each storage space has a number, increasing till N.

When someone drops their package, it is assigned the first available space. The packages could also be picked up, in this case the space becomes vacant.
Example: If the total capacity was 4. and 1 and 2 are full the third person to come in will be assigned the space 3. If 1, 2 and 3 were full and the 2nd space becomes vacant, the next person to come will be assigned the space 2.

The packages they drop have 2 unique properties, assigned for immediate identification. First they are color coded based on their content and second they are assigned a unique identification number(UIN).

What we want is to query the system:

1. When the input is color, show all the UIN associated with this color.
2. When the input is color, show all the numbers where these packages are placed(storage space number).
3. Show where an item with a given UIN is placed, i.e. storage space number.

I would like to know how which Data Structures to use for this case, so that the system works as efficiently as possible?
And I am not given which of these operations os most frequent, which means I will have to optimise for all the cases.

Please take a note, even though the query process is not directly asking for storage space number, but when an item is removed from the store it is removed by querying from the storage space number.

Comment: I think you need two: one sorting the vacancies by index and the other the actual storage. Unless you sort the storage itself

Comment: @efekctive Not very sure about it. So what I think as of now, I could use a min heap for getting the vacancies, A `Map<Color, Object>` to store the color and corresponding UID and storage space number(both in object). And another `Map<UID, Storage_Space_Number>`.  The problem with this is when I need to remove something from the space I would have to do two `N` iterations in the maps.

Comment: heap sorting vacancies, two maps + a backbone? Or mapping objects from the heap?

Comment: @efekctive backbone?

Comment: linear storage/array

Comment: what  you need a linear storage for?

Comment: I don't think you need it with the heap. I was just thinking out loud all the information

Comment: Yes, so this is what my thoughts are, just wanted to hear from others. maybe a better solutions pops up. Don't you think I am using way too many DSs for this?

Comment: It makes sense if speed is essential and space is plenty. You can always have only the heap and go through it

Comment: It looks as though you have two keys - UIN dependent on color dependent on content - to these items, which also don't require storage in a particular order, given your description.  Why not then create UINs based on a codification of the color, say with a prefix corresponding to the color code, and use a map of hashmaps?  Then you can refer to the color by UIN prefix, and the UIN by color key.

Comment: @AdrianM. even though that would have simplified the problem, but I am afraid this can't be done. This is how the problem is designed.

Comment: Why you say you want to implement this "as efficiently as possible", do you mean time efficiency, space efficiency, or some combination?

Comment: @jacobm I mean that I need to keep a balance between time and space complexity. I don't want to end up using a `Map` for all the data and have it completely time efficient and ignore the space complexity and vice versa.

Comment: Each requirement needs clear acceptance criteria. So please define "efficiency" and "balance" and how they are calculated/rated. Otherwise this question will just result in endless debate, not in a clear solution. I have voted to close the question. I will remove my vote if you specify clear acceptance criteria.

Comment: @kriegaex Unfortunately I don't have any acceptance criteria nor does the question states it. All I am looking for is a balance between space and time. I have already posted my thoughts in the comments about an approach and am looking for something better. So imagine if you will, you face this problem in real world, which approach would you take, with the information in hand.

Comment: Forget it, this is not a question format for StackOverflow. We have nothing: no volumetrics (storage size, frequency of change etc.), no criteria what is fast enough (lookup, add, delete complexity), small enough (RAM) or anything else which might be helpful. I strongly suggest to either update or delete the question. Just look at the number of comments so far! It is not going to lead anywhere but to debate, as I said before.

Comment: I cannot see why remove query need two N iterations.
For remove query, I guess you need to remove the corresponding iterm in Map<UID, Storage_Space_Number> and Map<Color, Object>.

If I understand it correctly, you know the storage space number for remove query. Then maybe you can use Map<storage space number, UID> to find out the UID. Similarly you can use another map to find out the color. Then given color and UID, you should be able to remove the items in Map<UID, Storage_Space_Number> and Map<Color, Object> efficiently.

Comment: How many different colors can be there? Are they arbitrary RGB values or is there a predefined set of color codes?

Comment: @user3290797 there are no predefined color values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the storage space number I used a min heap approach, `PriorityQueue`. This works in O(log n) time, removal and insertion both.

I used 2 BiMaps, self-created data structures, for storing the mapping between UIN, color and storage space number. These BiMaps used internally a HashMap and an array of size N.

In first BiMap(BiMap1), a `HashMap<color, Set<StorageSpace>>` stores the mapping of color to the list of storage spaces's. And a String array `String[] colorSpace` which stores the color at the storage space index.

In the Second BiMap(BiMap2), a `HashMap<UIN, storageSpace> stores the mapping between UIN and storageSpace. And a string array`String[] uinSpace` stores the UIN at the storage space index.

Querying is straight forward with this approach:

1. **When the input is color, show all the UIN associated with this color.**
         Get the List of storage spaces from BiMap1, for these spaces use the array in BiMap2 to get the corresponding UIN's.
2. **When the input is color, show all the numbers where these packages are placed(storage space number).** Use BiMap1's HashMap to get the list.
3. **Show where an item with a given UIN is placed, i.e. storage space number.** Use BiMap2 to get the values from the HashMap.

Now when we are given a storage space to remove, both the BiMaps have to be updated. In BiMap1 get the entry from the array, get the corersponding Set, and remove the space number from this set. From BiMap2 get the UIN from the array, remove it and also remove it from the HashMap.

For both the BiMaps the removal and the insert operations are O(1). And the Min heap works in O(Log n), hence the total time complexity is O(Log N)

Comment: Why do you have the first map of `HashMap<color, List<StorageSpace>>`? Why not map to a `Set<StorageSpace>`? In the worst case you are causing O(_N_) time for search when it can clearly just be O(_1_).

Comment: ...the solution you are giving is not always O(_1_) because your operations are also working with a heap for getting the new StorageSpace and adding back a freed StorageSpace. Both those ops are O(_Log N_). Your solution has a worst case time of O(_N_) for remove because the worst case time of *all involved operations to remove a package* have a step which is O(_N_). Did I wrongly analyzed something?

Comment: @displayName That is correct, I changed the implementation based on your suggestion and updated the complexity too.

Answer (score 3):

You have mentioned three queries that you want to make. Let's handle them one by one.

I cannot think of a single Data Structure that can help you with all three queries at the same time. So I'm going to give an answer that has three Data Structures and you will have to maintain all the three DS's state to keep the application running properly. Consider that as the cost of getting a respectably fast performance from your application for the desired functionality.

---

> When the input is color, show all the UIN associated with this color.

Use a HashMap that maps Color to a Set of UIN. Whenever an item:

- is added - See if the color is present in the HashMap. If yes, add this UIN to the set else create a new entry with a new set and add the UIN then.
- is removed - Find the set for this color and remove this UIN from the set. If the set is now empty, you may remove this entry altogether.

---

> When the input is color, show all the numbers where these packages are placed.

Maintain a HashMap that maps UIN to the number where an incoming package is placed. From the HashMap that we created in the previous case, you can get the list of all UINs associated with the given Color. Then using this HashMap you can get the number for each UIN which is present in the set for that Color.

So now, when a package is to be added, you will have to add the entry to previous HashMap in the specific Color bucket and to this HashMap as well. On removing, you will have to `.Remove()` the entry from here.

---

Finally,

> Show where an item with a given UIN is placed.

If you have done the previous, you already have the HashMap mapping UINs to numbers. This problem is only a sub-problem of the previous one.

---

The third DS, as I mentioned at the top, will be a Min-Heap of ints. The heap will be initialized with the first *N* integers at the start. Then, as the packages will come, the heap will be polled. The number returned will represent the storage space where this package is to be put. If the storage unit is full, the heap will be empty. Whenever a package will be removed, its number will be added back to the heap. Since it is a min-heap, the minimum number will bubble up to the top, satisfying your case that when 4 and 2 are empty, the next space to be filled will be 4.

---

Let's do a **Big O analysis of this solution** for completion.

- *Time for initialization:* of this setup will be O(*N*) because we will have to initialize a heap of *N*. The other two HashMaps will be empty to begin with and therefore will incur no time cost.
- *Time for adding a package:* will include time to get a number and then make appropriate entries in the HashMaps. To get a number from heap will take O(*Log N*) time at max. Addition of entries in HashMaps will be O(1). Hence a worst case overall time of O(*Log N*).
- *Time for removing a package:* will also be O(*Log N*) at worst because the time to remove from the HashMaps will be O(1) only while, the time to add the freed number back to min-heap will be upper bounded by O(*Log N*).

Comment: I realized I didn't add the space complexity. Since the min-heap will be initialized with N elements and both HashMaps will be empty at the start, it will be a O(N) space at the beginning. Then on, for every n taken out of min-heap, you will add a max of 1 entry each in the HashMaps, hence the total space will never exceed O(2N), which will effectively be O(N). Thus the space complexity of this solution is O(N) and time complexity is O(Log N)

Comment: I think you forgot to take into consideration that while removing an item from the store we only have the `storage space number`(the note part). Taking this into consideration, we would have to iterate the 2nd Map to get this storage space, which would make the querying process liner.

Comment: @rd22: Ok, I see. For this operation to be quick, we need to have another mapping of Storage Number to UIN. For this, we have another O(_N_) space used, but if time is more important than space for you, then this would be a minimum cost you would have to pay.  With this hash map, the deletion will increase by constant time and that would be dwarfed by O(_Log N_) of the heap, finally keeping the same upper bound. Yes... more overhead... but that's the price (in terms of complexity and space) I would pay to keep my application quick. There is obviously the O(_N_) time solution that you mention.

Comment: I understand, I wrote a solution keeping all the aspects in mind, and making the solution in O(1) time for almost all the parts. But I am afraid if I used way to much space, please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/41972677/1515111

Answer (score 1):

This smells of homework or really bad management.

Either way, I have decided to do a version of this where you care most about query speed but don't care about memory or a little extra overhead to inserts and deletes. That's not to say that I think that I'm going to be burning memory like crazy or taking forever to insert and delete, just that I'm focusing most on queries.

Tl;DR - to solve your problem, I **use a PriorityQueue, an Array, a HashMap, and an ArrayListMultimap** (from guava, a common external library), each one to solve a different problem.

The following section is working code that walks through a few simple inserts, queries, and deletes. This next bit isn't actually Java, since I chopped out most of the imports, class declaration, etc. Also, it references another class called 'Packg'. That's just a simple data structure which you should be able to figure out just from the calls made to it.

*Explanation is below the code*

```
import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;

private PriorityQueue<Integer> openSlots;
private Packg[] currentPackages;
Map<Long, Packg> currentPackageMap;
private ArrayListMultimap<String, Packg> currentColorMap;
private Object $outsideCall;


public CrazyDataStructure(int howManyPackagesPossible) {
    $outsideCall = new Object();
    this.currentPackages = new Packg[howManyPackagesPossible];
    openSlots = new PriorityQueue<>();
    IntStream.range(0, howManyPackagesPossible).forEach(i -> openSlots.add(i));//populate the open slots priority queue
    currentPackageMap = new HashMap<>();
    currentColorMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
}

/*
 * args[0] = integer, maximum # of packages
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int howManyPackagesPossible = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    CrazyDataStructure cds = new CrazyDataStructure(howManyPackagesPossible);
    cds.addPackage(new Packg(12345, "blue"));
    cds.addPackage(new Packg(12346, "yellow"));
    cds.addPackage(new Packg(12347, "orange"));
    cds.addPackage(new Packg(12348, "blue"));
    System.out.println(cds.getSlotsForColor("blue"));//should be a list of {0,3}
    System.out.println(cds.getSlotForUIN(12346));//should be 1 (0-indexed, remember)
    System.out.println(cds.getSlotsForColor("orange"));//should be a list of {2}
    System.out.println(cds.removePackage(2));//should be the orange one
    cds.addPackage(new Packg(12349, "green"));
    System.out.println(cds.getSlotForUIN(12349));//should be 2, since that's open
}

public int addPackage(Packg packg)
{
    synchronized($outsideCall)
    {
        int result = openSlots.poll();
        packg.setSlot(result);
        currentPackages[result] = packg;
        currentPackageMap.put(packg.getUIN(), packg);
        currentColorMap.put(packg.getColor(), packg);
        return result;
    }
}

public Packg removePackage(int slot)
{
    synchronized($outsideCall)
    {
        if(currentPackages[slot] == null)
            return null;
        else
        {
            Packg packg = currentPackages[slot];
            currentColorMap.remove(packg.getColor(), packg);
            currentPackageMap.remove(packg.getUIN());
            currentPackages[slot] = null;
            openSlots.add(slot);//return slot to priority queue
            return packg;
        }
    }
}

public List<Packg> getUINsForColor(String color)
{
    synchronized($outsideCall)
    {
        return currentColorMap.get(color);
    }
}

public List<Integer> getSlotsForColor(String color)
{
    synchronized($outsideCall)
    {
        return currentColorMap.get(color).stream().map(packg -> packg.getSlot()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

public int getSlotForUIN(long uin)
{
    synchronized($outsideCall)
    {
        if(currentPackageMap.containsKey(uin))
            return currentPackageMap.get(uin).getSlot();
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

I use 4 different data structures in my class.

***PriorityQueue*** I use the priority queue to keep track of all the open slots. It's log(n) for inserts and constant for removals, so that shouldn't be too bad. Memory-wise, it's not particularly efficient, but it's also linear, so that won't be too bad.

***Array*** I use a regular Array to track by slot #. This is linear for memory, and constant for insert and delete. If you needed more flexibility in the number of slots you could have, you might have to switch this out for an ArrayList or something, but then you'd have to find a better way to keep track of 'empty' slots.

***HashMap*** ah, the HashMap, the golden child of BigO complexity. In return for some memory overhead and an annoying capital letter 'M', it's an awesome data structure. Insertions are reasonable, and queries are constant. I use it to map between the UIDs and the slot for a Packg.

***ArrayListMultimap*** the only data structure I use that's not plain Java. This one comes from Guava (Google, basically), and it's just a nice little shortcut to writing your own Map of Lists. Also, it plays nicely with nulls, and that's a bonus to me. This one is probably the least efficient of all the data structures, but it's also the one that handles the hardest task, so... can't blame it. this one allows us to grab the list of Packg's by color, in constant time relative to the number of slots and in linear time relative to the number of Packg objects it returns.

When you have this many data structures, it makes inserts and deletes a little cumbersome, but those methods should still be pretty straight-forward. If some parts of the code don't make sense, I'll be happy to explain more (by adding comments in the code), but I think it should be mostly fine as-is.

Comment: Data races are in the provided code. One of them leads to possible NPE. For instance, here `if(currentPackageMap.containsKey(uin)) return currentPackageMap.get(uin).getSlot();` can be thrown NPE when another thread manages `currentPackageMap`.

Comment: @Gregory.K added synchronization blocks to those methods - I suppose I should have either left it completely non-thread safe or completely thread-safe

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention the no external library rule, and synchronization is not needed, this is a linear problem. I solved it using a similar approach. Keeping everything in almost constant time retrieval. Will share my approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Query 3**: Use a hash map, key is UIN, value is object (storage space number,color) (and any more information of the package). Cost is O(1) to query, insert or delete. Space is O(k), with k is the current number of UINs.

**Query 1 and 2** : Use hash map + multiple link lists

Hash map, key is color, value is pointer(or reference in Java) to link list of corresponding UINs for that color.

Each link list contains UINs.

For query 1: ask hash map, then return corresponding link list. Cost is O(k1) where k1 is the number of UINs for query color. Space is O(m+k1), where m is the number of unique color.

For query 2: do query 1, then apply query 3. Cost is O(k1) where k1 is the number of UINs for query color. Space is O(m+k1), where m is the number of unique color.

**To Insert:** given color, number and UIN, insert in hash map of query 3 an object (num,color); hash(color) to go to corresponding link list and insert UIN.

**To Delete:** given UIN, ask query 3 for color, then ask query 1 to delete UIN in link list. Then delete UIN in hash map of query 3.

Bonus: To manage to storage space, the situation is the same as memory management in OS: [read more](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~sschang/OS-Qual/memory/Memory.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to do with SegmentTree.
Just store a position in each place and query **min** it will match with vacant place, when you capture a place just assign 0 to this place.
Package information possible store in separate array.

- Initiall it have following values:
- 1 2 3 4
- After capturing it will looks following:
- 0 2 3 4
- After capturing one more it will looks following:
- 0 0 3 4
- After capturing one more it will looks following:
- 0 0 0 4
- After cleanup 2 it will looks follwong:
- 0 2 0 4
- After capturing one more it will looks following:
- 0 0 0 4

ans so on.

If you have segment tree to fetch min on range it possible to done in **O(LogN)** for each operation.

Here my implementation in C#, this is easy to translate to C++ of Java.

```
public class SegmentTree
{
    private int Mid;
    private int[] t;

    public SegmentTree(int capacity)
    {
        this.Mid = 1;
        while (Mid <= capacity) Mid *= 2;
        this.t = new int[Mid + Mid];


        for (int i = Mid; i < this.t.Length; i++) this.t[i] = int.MaxValue;
        for (int i = 1; i <= capacity; i++) this.t[Mid + i] = i;
        for (int i = Mid - 1; i > 0; i--) t[i] = Math.Min(t[i + i], t[i + i + 1]);
    }

    public int Capture()
    {
        int answer = this.t[1];
        if (answer == int.MaxValue)
        {
            throw new Exception("Empty space not found.");
        }

        this.Update(answer, int.MaxValue);

        return answer;
    }

    public void Erase(int index)
    {
        this.Update(index, index);
    }

    private void Update(int i, int value)
    {
        t[i + Mid] = value;
        for (i = (i + Mid) >> 1; i >= 1; i = (i >> 1))
            t[i] = Math.Min(t[i + i], t[i + i + 1]);
    }
}
```

Here example of usages:

```
    int n = 4;
    var st = new SegmentTree(n);

    Console.WriteLine(st.Capture());
    Console.WriteLine(st.Capture());
    Console.WriteLine(st.Capture());
    st.Erase(2);
    Console.WriteLine(st.Capture());
    Console.WriteLine(st.Capture());
```